# Adding icon for node shape using networkx and pyvis (python)

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, pyvisa

I am new to netwrokx and pyvis and am making a small network to display the different shapes possible for each node. I managed to use all the shapes except for icons. I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything useful and the examples available did not work with my code I would appreciate it if anyone could help me figure this out.

here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import xlrd #used to access the external excel file
import pyvis
from pyvis.network import Network
import pandas as pd
import textwrap

df = pd.read_csv("Visualizer\Data\EECS2311\shapes.csv",encoding='cp1252')

G=nx.Graph()

nodes = []

p1 = df['person1']
p2 = df['person2']
p3 = df['person3']
p4 = df['person4']
p5 = df['person5']
p6 = df['person6']
p7 = df['person7']
p8 = df['person8']
p9 = df['person9']
p10 = df['person10']
p11 = df['person11']
p12 = df['person12']
p13 = df['person13']
p14 = df['person14']

data = zip(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14)

for e in data:
    person1 = e[0]
    G.add_node(person1, shape="ellipse")
    person2 = e[1]
    G.add_node(person2, shape="circle")
    person3 = e[2]
    G.add_node(person3, shape="database")
    person4 = e[3]
    G.add_node(person4, shape="box")
    person5 = e[4]
    G.add_node(person5, shape="text")

    person6 = e[5]
    G.add_node(person6, shape="image", image="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hello-funny-person-simple-cartoon-260nw-1311467669.jpg")
    person7 = e[6]
    G.add_node(person7, shape="circularImage", image="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hello-funny-person-simple-cartoon-260nw-1311467669.jpg")
    person8 = e[7]
    G.add_node(person8, shape="diamond")
    person9 = e[8]
    G.add_node(person9, shape="dot")
    person10 = e[9]
    G.add_node(person10, shape="star")
    person11 = e[10]
    G.add_node(person11, shape="triangle")
    person12 = e[11]
    G.add_node(person12, shape="triangleDown")
    person13 = e[12]
    G.add_node(person13, shape="square")
    person14 = e[13]
    G.add_node(person14, shape="icon", icon="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/hello-funny-person-simple-cartoon-260nw-1311467669.jpg")

    nodes.append((person1, person2))
    nodes.append((person2, person3))
    nodes.append((person3, person4))
    nodes.append((person4, person5))
    nodes.append((person5, person6))
    nodes.append((person6, person7))
    nodes.append((person7, person8))
    nodes.append((person8, person9))
    nodes.append((person9, person10))
    nodes.append((person10, person11))
    nodes.append((person11, person12))
    nodes.append((person12, person13))
    nodes.append((person13, person14))
    

options = {
  
  "layout": {
    "hierarchical": {
      "enabled": True,
      "levelSeparation": 300,
      "nodeSpacing": 165,
      "treeSpacing": 305,
      "direction": "LR"
    }
  },
  "physics": {
    "hierarchicalRepulsion": {
      "centralGravity": 0,
      "nodeDistance": 110,
    },
    "minVelocity": 0.75,
    "solver": "hierarchicalRepulsion"
  }
}

G.add_edges_from(nodes)
G2 = Network(height="800px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white", select_menu=True, filter_menu=True, directed=True)
G2.from_nx(G)
G2.options = options


neighbor_map = G2.get_adj_list()

for node in G2.nodes:
    node["value"] = len(neighbor_map[node["id"]])
    #to wrap long labels:
    id_string = node["label"]
    width = 20
    wrapped_strings = textwrap.wrap(id_string, width)
    wrapped_id =""; 
    for line in wrapped_strings:
        wrapped_id = textwrap.fill(id_string, width)
    node["label"] = wrapped_id
        
    
#G2.show_buttons()


G2.show("shapes.html")
```

and here is my .csv file:

```
person1,person2,person3,person4,person5,person6,person7,person8,person9,person10,person11,person12,person13,person14
 ellipse, circle, database,box,text,image, circularImage,diamond,dot,star,triangle,triangleDown,square,icon
"ellipse shape displays label inside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""ellipse""","circle shape displays label inside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""circle""","database shape displays label inside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""database""","box shape displays label inside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""box""","only displays text. To use this simply set shape =""text""","image displays a image with label outside. To use set shape=""image"", image=""url"". Note: requires link to image","circularImage displays a circular image with label outside. To use set shape="" circularImage"", image=""url"". Note: requires link to image","diamond shape displays label outside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""diamond""","dot shape displays label outside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""dot""","star shape displays label outside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""star""","triangle shape displays label outside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""triangle""","triangleDown shape displays label outside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""triangleDown""","square shape displays label outside the shape. To use this simply set shape =""square""","icon displays a circular image with label outside. To use set shape="" icon"", image=""url"". Note: requires link to image"
```

ps. forgive the heading for the csv file :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, I just want to help you shrink your code so you can debug it more easily.

#### Use the DataFrame directly

You're doing a ton of extra work to get at your data, assigning to temporary variables, then zipping them together. They are already together! To loop over the things in row 0 of the DataFrame try this:

```
for item in df.loc[0]:
    print(item)
```

There's also a function in NetworkX, `nx.from_pandas_dataframe()`, that will create a network directly from a DataFrame... but you can only add edge attributes with that, not node attributes.

Then again...

#### Maybe dn't even use a DataFrame

Pandas is a convenient way to load CSVs, but your data isn't all that well-suited to this data structure. A `dict` would be better. It's a kind of mapping, in your case from node names to a node attribute.

Fortunately, there's a fairly easy way to get a `dict` from your DataFrame:

```
df.T.to_dict()[0]
```

This 'transposes' the DataFrame (turns the rows into columns) then turns the result into a `dict`. Then the `[0]` gives you the only column in the data.

This way you can avoid needing to repeat all your data (the mapping from person number to symbol) in your code.

Then again...

#### Maybe don't even use a dictionary

Any time you are mapping from a continuous set of numbers to some other objects (like `person1`, `person2`, etc) you might as well just use a list. Everything is indexed by position, which is basically what you have already. So you could just store your data like `['ellipse', 'circle', 'dot']` etc.

Then again...

#### Maybe don't even store the data

It turns out all these symbols are already defined in `matplotlib`. Have a look at:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
Line2D.markers
```

It's a dictionary of all the markers! If you want to try all of them, then you can just use these, no need to define anything.

#### Use `zip` to add your edges

`zip` is great for combining two or more lists, or combining a list with itself but with some offset. You can step over the nodes and make edges like so:

```
nodes = list(G.nodes)
for u, v in zip(nodes, nodes[1:]):
    G.add_edge(u, v)
```

#### General advice

- Try to avoid using tools like `pandas` just to load data. In my experience, it often introduces a bunch of complexity you don't need.
- Get something small and simple working before making it more complex, e.g. with URLs of images.
- You can store dictionaries easily as JSON text files. Check out the `json` module.

Again, sorry for not directly answering your question. But I feel like all this should help get your code down to something that is much easier to debug.